# How to insert php variable inside a double quoted php string

Tags: php

How can I insert a php variable inside my html string? I tried to do it like this, but it won't run. Please refer to the code below.

```
<?php 
  $a['id'] = 1;
  $html .= '<a href="{$a['id']}">Link</a>';
?>
```

Comment: how about fixing the typos? `$a['id'] = 1;`

Comment: Fix the typos. Concatenate variable, or use double quotes and escape the ones for attribute encapsulation.

Comment: Above is just an example. What if I wanted to `echo` that variable inside a double coated string. @Dagon

Comment: I edited now., Sorry I missed that one

Comment: so many dupes. sigh no one bothers to search

Comment: Why down vote if already fixed the typo?

Comment: becasue its a lazy question that could of been answered with very little effort using any search engine

Comment: Coz sometimes using search engine leads us to many options and sometimes incorrect answers. That's why I use stackoverflow to receive direct help from professionals. But I know your point too. Thanks

Comment: look at the first match using your exact words: https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=What+if+I+wanted+to+echo+that+variable+inside+a+double+coated+string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed out the closing `'`. Also, you need to concat them using the PHP concatenation operator `.` to join the string with the variable:

```
$a['id'] = 1;
$html .= '<a href="' . $a['id'] . '">Link</a>';
```

Comment: Working. Thanks for the quick answer

Comment: @claudios You're welcome